# \uline within a pgfmath expression produces an error

Tags: errors, expansion, pgfmath

Why does using `\uline` within a `pgfmath` expression result in an error?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{width("\uline{blabla}")}
\end{document}
```

The error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ULset ->\UL@setULdepth \def \UL@leadtype 
                                          {\leaders \hrule \@height \UL@heig...
l.6 ...se{width("\let\uline\relax\uline{blabla}")}

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\UL@on #1->\leavevmode 
                       \UL@ender \let \UL@on \UL@onin \everymath {\UL@hrest ...
l.6 ...se{width("\let\uline\relax\uline{blabla}")}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

My `\uline` is embedded in some other macro, so I can't simply not write it there. I had the idea to temporarily undefine `\uline` within the math expression (I don't need it to calculate the width, right!), but it only made matters more misterious: the error persists (it seems that `\let` is never executed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{width("\let\uline\relax\uline{blabla}")}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will teach you not using underlining. ;-)

Comment: ;-) Don't worry, it wasn't for text. Just to signal that something is a predicate.

Comment: `\pgfmathparse{width("...")}` is bound to failure whenever there's something in the argument that doesn't survive `\edef` (`\textbf`, for instance). So I guess that the `\sbox` method is better in any case when you can't fully control the text.

Comment: Although the `\sbox` and `\wd` way is certainly preferable and the most safe. With the package `etoolbox`, one can simply do `\robustify\uline` (which protects `\uline` from expansion by `\edef`) and `\pgfmathprint{width("\uline{blabla}")}` will give `26.66675` then. (Of course, this doesn’t work if you don’t know what to expect.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has all the signs of premature expansion, but the usual `\protect` methods don't seem to work here. You can make things safe by using a box register:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\sbox{0}{\uline{blabla}}
\typeout{\the\wd0}
\pgfmathparse{width("\usebox{0}")}
\typeout{\pgfmathresult}
\end{document}
```

runs without error and `\pgfmathresult` gets the right value:

```
26.66675pt
26.66675
```

Comment: Right, he could just use `\pgfmathparse{+\wd0}` then. :)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel well in this case you clearly don't need to parse at all since it's a fixed known width you could just use `\wd0`, but that's an artefact of a small example. You might need to make some macro-supplied text safe to use in a pgfmathparse expression and passing it through a box register is one way to do that.

Answer (score 5):

There is one more inbetween check and as David Carlisle noticed it causes an early expansion. So more protection helps. This is also needed if the text is bold with `\textbf` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{width("\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\uline{blabla}")}
\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't work if the text to measure is passed as argument.

Comment: @egreg You mean like `\textbf{\mytext}`

Comment: I guess that nobody uses `\pgfmathparse` in the wild and probably it's inside some macro to which the text is passed as argument: `\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\pgfmathparse{width("#1")}...}` and in this case there's no possibility of adding `\noexpand` in unknown places.

Comment: @egreg Oh I see now. But indeed it's not too smart to use that function in such cases. Instead boxing it inside `\foo` group directly and using `\wd` is much easier. The usage is for places where you can't escape and execute TeX commands easily.

Comment: @egreg This was indeed the case.

Comment: @percusse Thanks, I understand now why this happens. Btw, doesn't the need to (double) protect heavily limit the usage of `width`? Couldn't it work without early expansion?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović I'll read properly the math function handling before I say something stupid :)

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Oh, I've forgotten to respond my apologies. I've checked the function out and I don't have an answer for the reason for such restriction. Maybe it was too much of a hassle to code it fail-safe. However, you can come up with your own flavor by copying and modifying the function from the `pgfmathfunction.misc.code.tex` line 202.

Answer (score 3):

## Fix via `\pgfmath@selectfont`

This works good for the combination `\uline` and `width`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\pgf@tempa{\let\uline\relax}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfmath@selectfont\expandafter{\expandafter\pgf@tempa\pgfmath@selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\uline{blabla}

\pgfmathparse{width("\uline{blabla}")}
\pgfmathresult

\uline{blabla}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## `\let`

You can temporarily eliminate `\uline` if you use `\let\uline\relax` outside of `\pgfmathparse`. Localize this and `\uline` works fine in the rest of the document.

To access the result outside of this group we need to define `\pgfmathresult` global (via `\xdef`).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \let\uline\relax
  \pgfmathparse{width("\uline{blabla}")}%
  \xdef\pgfmathresult{\pgfmathresult}% make \pgfmathresult global
\endgroup
\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is of course a good idea, it just not feasible in the particular case. The computed value gets assigned locally and I have no control over that...

Comment: @SašoŽivanović I’m interested in your particular case. But it was rather an answer to your question’s last part. But maybe my updated answer can help you. Though, I would go with `\sbox` and `\wd` anyway.

Comment: `\sbox`+`\wd` is what I used in the end indeed. My case has to do with my tree-drawing package [forest](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest): I had to do some manual adjustment (node-positioning algorithm doesn't take edge labels into account). Values given to `dimen`-type options of the nodes are automatically parsed by `pgfmath` (that's why using pgfmath's `width` was my first choice), but the result is assigned locally. Thus, if I enclosed the processing of the option into a group (which can be done using key `TeX`), the assignment would be forgotten (I guess I'd also get errors).