# Text alignment below horizontal axis with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to align the labels *a* and *b* under the *x* axis to the same baseline.  The alignment is wrong on the left-hand side of the picture. It is correct on the right-hand side, but isn't there a simpler way to achieve this (that is, without finding a value for `below=` by trial and error)?

Left-hand side:

```
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]%
      \draw [<->] (7,0) node[below left]{$x$} -- (0,0) -- (0,7);
      \draw [thick] (0,0) -- (6.5,6.5);%
      \node [below] at (2,0) {$a$};%
      \node [below] at (5,0) {$b$};%
      \end{tikzpicture}%
```

Right-hand side:

```
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]%
      \draw [<->] (7,0) node[below left]{$x$} -- (0,0) -- (0,7);
      \draw [thick] (0,0) -- (6.5,6.5);%
      \node [below=2.735] at (2,0) {$a$};%
      \node [below] at (5,0) {$b$};%
      \end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image]

Comment: Related: [Q107227](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107227), [Q134983](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134983) and many more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to add a `\vphantom{b}` in the `a` node. This inserts a zero-width rule the height of `b`, so basically makes the height of the `a` node the same as the `b` node.

Another option is to place the node relative to the bottom of the `b` node. First give the `b` node a name/label (`\node [below] (b) at (5,0) {$b$};`), then place the second node with `\node [above] at (b.south -| 2,0) {$a$};`.

A third choice is to set the `text height` to be the height of a `$b$`. You can get that height width the `\heightof` macro, so set `text height=\heightof{$b$}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]%
\draw [<->] (7,0) node[below left]{$x$} -- (0,0) -- (0,7);
\draw [thick] (0,0) -- (6.5,6.5);
\node [below] at (2,0) {$a\vphantom{b}$};
\node [above] at (b.south -| 3,0) {$a$};
\node [below] at (5,0) {$b$};
\node [below,text height=\heightof{$b$}] at (4,0) {$a$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```